# Sending form with PHP through AJAX with no page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

So I have this code to POST data with PHP and AJAX without redirecting page, I'm using the same script on the login page. The login page works like a charm but the other pages don't. The only diffeence between these is that login php script page uses `if (empty($_POST) === false) {}` and the other pages use `if (isset($_POST['save-settings'])) {}`. I don't know what do to.. Here below is the script I'm using.

HTML BUTTON

```
<input id="save-settings" class="submit" type="submit" name="save-settings" value="Save" onclick="return false;" />
```

JS SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#save-settings").click(function() {
            var name        = $("#webname").val();
            var charset     = $("#webchar").val();
            var meta        = $("#webmeta").val();
            var description = $("#webdesc").val();
            var startsite   = $("#webstartsite").val();
            var starturl    = $("#webstartsiteurl").val();
            var footer      = $("#webfooter").val();

            $.post("../lib/action.php", {
                name: name,
                charset: charset,
                meta: meta,
                description: description,
                startsite: startsite,
                starturl: starturl,
                footer: footer
            }, function(data) {
                $("#gy-main-notification-bar").hide().html("<h1>!</h1><h2>" + data + "</h2>").slideDown(500);
                setTimeout(function() { $("#gy-main-notification-bar").slideUp(500) }, 2500);
            });
        });
    });
```

PHP SCRIPT

```
if(isset($_POST['save-settings'])) {
    $updatesettings = "UPDATE `settings` SET
    `name`='".escape($_POST['webname'])."',
    `charset`='".escape($_POST['webchar'])."',
    `meta`='".escape($_POST['webmeta'])."',
    `description`='".escape($_POST['webdesc'])."',
    `startsite`='".escape($_POST['webstartsite'])."',
    `starturl`='".escape($_POST['webstartsiteurl'])."',
    `footer`='".escape($_POST['webfooter'])."'
     WHERE `id`= 1";

     if ($update_settings = $db_connect->query($updatesettings)) {}
     echo 'Success!';
 }
```

I don't really want to change the `isset` to `empty` in the script due the fact that I have all my `"onclick"` script in one action.php file. When I remove `onclick="return:false;"` from input it works.. I'm so confused I appriciate any help!

Comment: since you are capturing the click event on #save-settings, why don't use a button input instead of a submit input? That way you don't need to intercept the standard behavior and don't need the onClick handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Forgot to include the post save-settings. You probably should've included it with the ajax post like this:

```
$.post("../lib/action.php", {
            'name': name,
            'charset': charset,
            'meta': meta,
            'save-settings': true,
            'description': description,
            'startsite': startsite,
            'starturl': starturl,
            'footer': footer
        },
```

change this in your sql statement for the correct posts

```
 `name`='".escape($_POST['name'])."',
`charset`='".escape($_POST['charset'])."',
`meta`='".escape($_POST['meta'])."',
`description`='".escape($_POST['description'])."',
`startsite`='".escape($_POST['startsite'])."',
`starturl`='".escape($_POST['starturl'])."',
`footer`='".escape($_POST['footer'])."'
 WHERE `id`= 1";
```

Comment: It should be `'save-settings': true,` because `-` isn't allowed in identifiers.

Comment: Thank you, it kond of works now.. kind of... the Success message is displayed however the mysql database updates with empty entries...

Comment: edited for you change that and you should be good to go @Dany

Comment: @SjoerdDeWit Thank you so much! By the way as I mentioned I use the same script for my login script, is it secure to process password through it?

Comment: Should not be a problem, javascript is client side so only that user should be able to see it @Dany

Answer (score 1):

Click event handler function can have event argument. When you catch this argument you can use preventDefault() method. With this method default action of click will be prevented and page won't be refreshed.

Change

```
$("#save-settings").click(function() {
        var name        = $("#webname").val();
```

to

```
$("#save-settings").click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var name        = $("#webname").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

writing `onclick="return false"` in HTML cancels the execution of the javascript code. just delete this `onclick="..."` and add `preventDefault()` like this to prevent form submittion

```
$("#save-settings").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   .....
```